# How to show sum as a time value in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a number of values in a SQL column called ACD_Time

At present these values are:

105
2933
1387
1079
971
627

With the total being 7102.

This is then fed into an SSRS report. In my SSRS report it is currently a sum, which is bringing back this value (7102). But what I actually need is to convert this into hours, minutes and seconds which in this instance would be 01:58:22

How do I go about converting the figure into a timed value

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the 7102 are the seconds and you want to get a timespan from it. You could do it like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s,  7102, 0), 114)
```

Comment: Hi Mono, yes that is correct. 7102 is the total number of seconds. 
After using an online converter, it's told me that would be 01:58:22

So I need a piece of code that would convert from 7102 to 01:58:22

Comment: Ye I posted you a code which would convert it into a varchar with 01:58:22 in SQL

Comment: But where would I place that as my SSRS calculation

It currently reads like this: =SUM(Fields!ACD_Time.Value) with ACD_Time being the column in SQL which is being totalled to give me 7102

But I need some sort of code that instead of showing it as 7102, it instead needs to be 01:58:22

Comment: 7102 is just one example, as i have plenty of other rows and columns that will require similar functions

Each column in SQL is currently being summed which is required but it then needs to be reflected as time values in ssrs

Comment: Try DateAdd(SECOND, ACD_Time.Value, 0)

Comment: It doesn't seem to like SECOND as a word in my expression. Is this just entered stand alone or does it have to follow after =SUM(Fields!ACD_Time.Value) at some juncture?

ThanksD

Comment: I dont use SRSS to be honest. Check out this maybe it will help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!MySecondsField.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Thanks very much Mono!